# marshal struct to xmlwith an extra tag

Tags: go

I'm developing a twilio telephone server in Go and have some structs that reference the xml to generate.

For instance:

```
type Say struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"Say"`

    Text string `xml:",chardata"`
}

type Response struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"Response"`
    Says []Say `xml:",omitempty"`
}
```

When the Says array is filled with two Say structs containing 'Something' and 'Something else' this generates:

```
<Response>
  <Say>Something</Say>
  <Say>Something else</Say>
</Response>
```

But after 'Something' is said out loud there is no pause and 'something else' comes right after that.

twilio created a Pause tag for that to let it pause a second.
So what I want is to have an xml generated like this:

```
<Response>
  <Say>Something</Say>
  <Pause></Pause>
  <Say>Something else</Say>
  <Pause></Pause>
</Response>
```

But how can this be represented in the go struct? How to squeeze in an extra Pause tag as a sibling of the Say tag?

```
type Say struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"Say"`

    Text string `xml:",chardata"`
    ???? Pause `xml:Pause,sibling?????`
}

type Response struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"Response"`
    Says []Say `xml:",omitempty"`
}
```

Comment: So basically you want to ensure that you have a valid sequence, in which a pause should only be following a `say` by means of struct tags?

Comment: yes thats what I want

Comment: Of the top of my head, this is not possible with just struct tags and sounds more like a job for XSD. You _could_ of course write a custom validator using a tokenizer, which fails if the first element encountered is a pause. Wether to use XSD or a custom validator heavily depends on your use case, however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution with the use of interfaces

```
type Say struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"Say"`

    Text string `xml:",chardata"`
}

type Response struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"Response"`
    Says []interface{}
}
```

The lack of an actual type name does not generate a 'Says' tag.

```
var r Response

r.Says = append(r.Says, Say { Text: "hello"})
```